# Error with overloaded operator+ C++

Tags: c++, matrix, multidimensional-array, operator-overloading, addition

I'm having a problem trying to add two 2D matrices with the overloaded operator+. I've successfully assigned the two matrices to two different arrays.

My errors are:

> In function `mathadd::matrices mathadd::operator+(mathadd::matrices&, mathadd::matrices&)':
>
> no matching function for call to `mathadd::matrices::matrices(double&)'
>
> candidates are: mathadd::matrices::matrices(const mathadd::matrices&)

In my int main() {} the main parts of this error are:

```
matrices sample;
double array1[4][4], array2[4][4], add[4][4];
add[4][4] = array1[4][4] + array2[4][4];
```

The overloaded operator definition is:

> ```
>      matrices operator +(matrices& p1, matrices& p2)
>       {
>            double addition[4][4];
>            for (int y = 0; y < 4; ++y )
>            {
>                for (int x = 0; x < 4; ++x )
>                {
>                     addition[4][4] = p1.get_array1() + p2.get_array2();
>                }
>             }
>             matrices sum(addition[4][4]); // This is where the error is.
>             return sum;
>       }
> ```

My class looks like this

```
class matrices
  {
        public:
               matrices();
               void assignment(double one[4][4], double two[4][4]);
               double get_array1() const {return first_array[4][4];}
               double get_array2() const {return second_array[4][4];} 
               matrices operator +(matrices& p1, matrices& p2);
        private:
                double first_array[4][4], second_array[4][4];
                //Initialized to 0 in constructor.
  };
```

I don't understand what this error means and I would appreciate any help in understanding what it means and how I can fix it.

Comment: You need to learn basic array operations and elementary C++ before you start overloading operators.  Learn to crawl before running.  More practically, write a function `add` that adds two matrices and returns the result: your problem is far before you overload an operator.

Answer (score 3):

`addition[4][4]` is a double out-of-bounds  array access to get the fifth `double` from the fifth `double[]` named by `addition`. Just pass the name `addition` instead of `addition[4][4]` in `matrices sum(addition[4][4])`.

So it should be

```
matrices sum(addition);
return sum;
```

That is only the source of your compiler error. You also have many logic errors in your code, such as the out-of-bounds array access I mentioned earlier, in the inner `for`-loop. You will have to fix these or else get undefined behavior.

Comment: I tried that already and it didn't work. I get the same error as before.

Answer (score 1):

You get an error because your `operator +` is defined for objects of type `matrices`, not for 2D arrays of `double`s. You need to construct matrices before adding them, like this:

First, add a constructor for `matrices` that takes `double[4][4]`. Then, change the signature of the `operator +` to be `static`, and take a `const` reference to its parameters:

```
static matrices operator +(const matrices& p1, const matrices& p2);
```

Now you can write this:

```
matrices add = matrices(array1) + matrices(array2);
```